# How to remove overhead caused by increasing number of CPU cores

Tags: performance, networking, linux-kernel, multicore

We have a situation where in a server with 8 core initializes a service in 6 minutes and the other server with 32 cpu-cores takes 35 minutes to initialize the service. After profiling it properly we have seen that it is because of two kernel APIs(get_counters and snmp_fold_field) which tries to collect data from each existing cores and as the number of cpu-cores increases execution time takes longer than expected.In order to reduce initialization time we thought to make extra cores disabled and later to initialization enable all the cpu cores.But in this approach also once we enable all cores synchronization happens on newly enabled cores as this is SMP kernel.

Can someone suggest us how to reduce overhead caused by increased CPU cores efficiently?

---

Instead code i would rather explain initialization functionality of this user defined system service.During its initialization this service plumbs virtual interfaces on configured IPs. To avoid overlapping IPs situation for each configured IP it creates an internal IP and all communication is done on the interfaces plumbed on internal IP.As the packet reaches to system with destination as configured IP , Mangling/NATting/Routing table rules are applied on the system to mange it.
An interface is also plumb for configured Ip to avoid IP forwarding.Our issue is when we scale our system configured for 1024 IPs on 8 core machine it takes 8 minutes and on 32 cores it takes 35 minutes.

On further debugging done using system profiling We saw that ARPtables/IPtables's kernel module is consuming most time in "get_counters()" and IP's kernel module is consuming time in snmp_fold_field(). If i simply disable ARPtables Mangling rules time drops to 18 minutes from 35 minutes.I can share the kernel modules's callstacks collected using profiler.

Comment: Write up a small program that shows the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A common bottleneck in applications utilizing multi-core is uncontrolled/-optimized access to shared resources. The biggest performance killer is the bus-lock (critical sections) followed by accesses to RAM, accesses to the L3 cache and accesses to the L2 cache. As long as a core is operating inside its own L1 (code and data) caches the only bottlenecks will be due to poorly-written code and badly-organized data. When two cores need to go outside their L1 caches they may collide when accessing their (shared) L2 cache. Who gets to go first? Is the data even there or must we move down into L3 or RAM to access it? For every further level required to find the data you're looking at a 3-4x time penalty.

Concerning your application it seems to have worked reasonably well because eight cores can only collide to a certain degree when accessing the shared resources. With thirty-two cores the problem becomes more than four times as large because you'll have four times the strain on the resource and four times as many cores to resolve who gets to access first. It's like a doorway: as long as a few people run in or out through the doorway now and then there's no problem. Someone approaching the doorway might stop a little to let the other guy through. Suddenly you have a situation where many people are running in and out and you'll not only have congestion, you'll have a traffic jam.

My advice to you is to experiment with restricting the number of threads (which will translate into number of cores) your application may utilize at any one time. The six minute startup time on eight cores could serve as a benchmark. You may find that it will execute faster on four cores than eight, not to mention thirty-two.

If this is the case and you still insist on running faster on thirty-two cores than you are today you're looking at an enormous amount of work both making the SNMP-server code more efficient and organizing your data to lessen the load on shared resources. Not for the faint-of-heart. You may end up re-writing the entire application.

Comment: Our application is using very less number of threads but we use third party applications like "ip","iptables" and "arptables" which internally call two apis get_sockopt() and recvmsg(). These APIs take longer time in kernel.Corresponding APIs in kernel for them are get_sockopt() and snmp_fold_field()[I mentioned them earlier].

Comment: You need to determine to what extent they contribute to the adverse overhead characteristics. Try experimenting by decreasing the number of IPs to see if it is possibler to find one sweet spot for four cores and another for thirty-two.